# Parameter T might not live long enough

Tags: rust

I'm currently learning Rust and I'm struggling with something I cannot manage to understand.

Consider the following code:

```rust
use std::cmp::{Ordering, Ord};

pub enum Error {
    ItemAlreadyExists,
}

pub trait BinaryTree<T: Ord> {
    fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> Result<(), Error>;
}

pub struct TreeNode<T> {
    data: T,
    left: Option<Box<BinaryTree<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<BinaryTree<T>>>,
}

impl<T> TreeNode<T> {
    pub fn new(data: T) -> Self {
        TreeNode {
            data,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Ord> BinaryTree<T> for TreeNode<T> {
    fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> Result<(), Error> {
        match value.cmp(&self.data) {
            Ordering::Less => match self.left.as_mut() {
                Some(left) => left.insert(value),
                None => Ok({ self.left = Some(Box::new(TreeNode::new(value))) }),
            },
            Ordering::Greater => match self.right.as_mut() {
                Some(right) => right.insert(value),
                None => Ok({ self.right= Some(Box::new(TreeNode::new(value))) }),
            },
            Ordering::Equal => Err(Error::ItemAlreadyExists),
        }
    }
}
```

This is a basic implementation of inserting a value in a binary tree.

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:35:47
   |
30 | impl<T: Ord> BinaryTree<T> for TreeNode<T> {
   |      -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...
...
35 |                 None => Ok({ self.left = Some(Box::new(TreeNode::new(value))) }),
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What does it mean by parameter `T` might not live enough? As far as I know, I'm moving `T` around, I'm not borrowing anything so I shouldn't worry about lifetimes, as everything's owned.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "I'm currently learning Rust" do yourself a favor and don't do linked list in Rust.

Comment: _"As far as I know, I'm moving T around, I'm not borrowing anything..."_ — Your function needs to work for _any_ `T`, including  types that hold references.